# Which is the safer method to define string constants

Tags: java, string, memory, standards

I am defining some String constants in my code using a separate file.

Will there be a difference in memory usage or other standards between the  examples provided below.

```
public static final String sample1 = "this is a sample string";

public static final String sample2 = "this "+"is a "+"sample "+"string";

public static final String sample3 = sample1+sample2;
```

Since I would be defining a large number of such string to be used across my
program I would like to know which is the correct method, to optimize memory usage. Expecting your suggestions.

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: I would recommend the first option.

Comment: i would also recommend the first option here.

The second option will create 5 objects of string in the string constant pool.

The Third option will create 3 objects of string in the string contant pool.

Comment: all the same, just a question of what you want to * express* - but what is more important IMO, all constants should be ALL UPPERCASE

Comment: @NaveenKulkarni They'll be combined by the compiler.

Comment: Note that while these are all the same, concatenation is often a good idea _when you're using a prefix_, such as with a number of configuration keys or metric names.

Comment: @Michu93 given they are absolutely identical, what criteria did you use to choose?

Comment: @StephenC Well, I thought that second and third String are builded like in loop so there will be more Strings in memory but you are right, if they are `static` they are exactly the same.

Comment: @Michu93 No. If they are `final` they are exactly the same. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: "... I thought that second and third String are builded like in loop ..." - I don't know what you mean by that.  But there is no loop.  And there would be no loop even if this was not a compile-time constant expression.  A multiple step runtime concatenation expression is compiled to a sequence of method calls, not a loop.

Answer (score 3):

These are all examples of *(compile time) constant expressions*.  The bytecode compiler (e.g. javac) will perform the concatenations so that there is a single string in the constant pool in the compiled ".class" file for the value assigned to `sample1` and `sample2`.  And the value of `sample3` is also a compile time constant ... since it is the concatenation of two other compile-time constant variables.

The rules that determine what is or is not a *constant expression* are lengthy ([JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) and [4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)), but:

- string literals are,
- `final` variables of type `String` are, provided that they are initialized to a compile time constant expression, and
- string concatenations are, provided that the operands are constant expressions (of certain types, including `String`).

Therefore, there is no difference between `sample1` and `sample2` in terms of performance, semantic correctness, memory utilization or code (".class" file) size.  The only difference is readability.  (And you can be the judge of that.)

(The value of `sample3` is clearly different to `sample1` and `sample2`.  It is a poor example.  But the *approaches* are the same in terms of those criteria.)

Comment: `static` does not appear in your link. The only operative keyword is `final`, as seen in the link to [#4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) from 'constant variables'.

Comment: Fixed.  (I was going to call >>you<< out on that point ... but I checked first.)   This stuff is too obscure for mere mortals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `static` variables are initialized whenever the class is first encountered. From a memory perspective, all 3 are equal since they load the same String into memory. The first option should be preferred simply because it is more readable.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that they only load _the same_ string because the compiler combines compile-time constant string values.

Comment: @RakibulIslam No. Its constituent strings are `final`, so known to the compiler at compile time, so concatenated at compile time. See the JLS.